# How to init/setup shell with custom bash file (not from .bachrc or profile or other shells)?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

This is the scenario: I used to develop code into an environment, and when I started it I did a "setup.ps1" or "init.ps1". What this code used to do, was to add in my shell /cmd instance all the variables that I needed. That means when I did "branch fo" it created my branch, or when did echo $blah, it did have blah initialized, debug command moved me in a debug folder with a lot of variables loaded.

Now, since I moved to Linux I want to have the same thing. However, just 2 weeks old in bash, and I see that everyone added things in .bashrc or .zshrc when the profile loads. Well, that's fine for me, but not for the project that's loaded by many devs. So, what I need is to use "source init.sh" or "bash setup.sh" and load all the variables for the console, so after that, I can start to work building, etc.

I tried to add items in this form, but of course, they don't work. It looks that dir cannot be source-ed, and source $setup does not work...

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e

dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
setup="$dir/services/deployment/setup.sh"
echo "loading $setup"
source $setup

function ftest() {
  echo "something"
}

export test1=ftest
export test2="test"
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Edit:
This is the error, that I get when sourcing the source.sh, that's added above.

```
➜  src git:(master) ✗ cat setup.sh
#!/bin/bash
set +e

dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
setup="$dir/services/deployment/setup.sh"
echo "loading $setup"
source $setup

function ftest() {
  echo "something"
}

export test1=ftest
export test2="test"#
➜  src git:(master) ✗ source setup.sh
setup.sh:4: bad math expression: operand expected at `/mnt/d/Rep...'
➜  src git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why `source $setup` wouldn't work.

Comment: How are you running the script that contains this code? It needs to be sourced if you want it to affect the interactive shell.

Comment: What do you mean by "it looks the dir cannot be source-ed"? You don't source a directory, you source individual files.

Comment: `bash` users don't add to `.zshrc`, that's just for `zsh`.

Comment: ➜  src git:(master) ✗ cat setup.sh
#!/bin/bash
set +e

dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
setup="$dir/services/deployment/setup.sh"
echo "loading $setup"
source $setup

function ftest() {
  echo "something"
}

export test1=ftest
export test2="test"#
➜  src git:(master) ✗ source setup.sh
setup.sh:4: bad math expression: operand expected at `/mnt/d/Rep...'
➜  src git:(master) ✗

Comment: I added the exception. As you can see, I expected this to work, but actually it does not. It fails at $(dir  command.

Comment: Please edit the question, formatted text isn't readable in comments.

Comment: What's on line 4 of `setup.sh`?

Comment: I added the formatted version in the edit, it's :dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216906/discussion-between-user3053247-and-barmar).

Comment: Are you sure you copied correctly?  An arithmetic expression is in `$((...))`.

Comment: Your code needs to *actually be complete enough to reproduce the error for someone else* to constitute a useful question. Try using an online interpreter like https://ideone.com/ to test whether your code produces the error you want help with when run on its own.

Comment: Also, bash and zsh are two completely different shells; they're incompatible with each other, sometimes gratuitously so. Tag for one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in either `bash` or `zsh`.